# Keyboard shortcut to switch focus from Chrome DevTools to web browser on Mac (follow up)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

(I am aware that there are similar threads such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12823333/702977) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10981973/702977) 3 years ago.
I tried their comments, but it did not work, so I re-ask the question, maybe there are changes during 3 years...)

I use `Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.4` and `Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit)`. I start to use `Chrome DevTools`, and I dock it into **separate window** from Chrome web browser.

As a result, the DevTools and the web browser are considered 2 windows belonging to the same application (ie, Chrome). <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> can be used to switch from the Chrome browser to the DevTools.

However, same as the old threads mentioned, <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> can **not** switch back from the DevTools to the web browser.

I have tried the comment of [Hugh Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30567119/702977) or [TMB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36868849/702977), however <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> on the DevTools does not lead me to the address bar of web browser. Additionally, typing `javascript:` in the address bar of web browser returns nothing. Maybe they meant the address bar for DevTools, does it exist?

Does anyone know how to make the above hack works, or have a solution for the general problem?

Comment: Cmd + ` allows me to switch back and forth between the undocked DevTools window and the main browser window fine, provided that you don't minimise either window.

Comment: I really need the DevTools to be undocked...

Comment: It is undocked as I said. I selected 'Undock into separate window' as the option and so I have a small DevTools window on top of my main. If I use Cmd + ` it hides and shows the DevTools window.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood... Cmd + ` did not let me switch from DevTools to web browser... lucky you...

Comment: Is the keyboard shortcut enabled for you? See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/iotI9Na.png

Comment: Yes, i just verified, it is enabled...

Comment: Make sure your DevTools window is in the same Desktop to use that shortcut. Alternatively, what you could do is make the DevTools full screen by pressing the green icon on the top left of the window. You can then switch between your browser in one Desktop and DevTools on the other with 4 finger swipe left and right. Seems convenient to me.